# automatically trim char fields from legacy database

Tags: entity-framework

How can i configure the entity framework to automatically trim the spaces from char(x) fields (using mssql server 10.50.2500) using a **Legacy** database (changing the field type is no option)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.Trim in your domain objects

Comment: That's what i'm already doing (using a helper method to just trim all string properties), but i was wondering if there's a built-in feature or field-translation hook in the entity framework to do this after fetching the data from the database.